# ASP.net Gridview "onSorting" event does not execute when column header is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple asp.net gridview with AllowSorting set to true. It is code I've used several times in other web pages without issue.

In this instance when I click the column header expecting the sort to happen I get nothing. I set a break point in the event method and that break point is never reached. I checked the Properties events and the onSorting event is set properly. I can't see any obvious errors, anyone else have this issue before?

```
                <asp:GridView ID="inputGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" CellPadding="5" OnRowCommand="inputGrid_RowCommand"
                    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="20" OnSorting="inputGrid_Sorting3"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="inputGrid_PageIndexChanging" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightBlue" PagerSettings-Position="Top" PageIndex="0">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Select"
                                    AutoPostBack="false"
                                    Text=""
                                    TextAlign="Right"
                                    OnCheckedChanged="Select_CheckedChanged"
                                    runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Font-Bold
                                    CommandName="UpdateField"
                                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                    Text="Edit" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Error"
                            SortExpression="errorMsg"
                            DataField="errorMsg" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Number"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorNbr"
                            DataField="controlVendorNbr" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Suffix"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorSuffix"
                            DataField="controlVendorSuffix" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Name"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorName"
                            DataField="controlVendorName" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Type"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorType"
                            DataField="controlVendorType" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Address"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorAddr1"
                            DataField="controlVendorAddr1" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="City"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorCity"
                            DataField="controlVendorCity" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="State"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorState"
                            DataField="controlVendorState" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Zip Code"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorZip"
                            DataField="controlVendorZip" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Status"
                            SortExpression="controlVendorStatus"
                            DataField="controlVendorStatus" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Number"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorNbr"
                            DataField="sxeVendorNbr" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Ship From"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorSequence"
                            DataField="sxeVendorSequence" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Name"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorName"
                            DataField="sxeVendorName" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Vendor Type"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorType"
                            DataField="sxeVendorType" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Address"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorAddr1"
                            DataField="sxeVendorAddr1" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="City"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorCity"
                            DataField="sxeVendorCity" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="State"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorState"
                            DataField="sxeVendorState" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Zip Code"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorZip"
                            DataField="sxeVendorZip" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Status"
                            SortExpression="sxeVendorStatus"
                            DataField="sxeVendorStatus" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Created Date"
                            SortExpression="createDate"
                            DataField="createDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Last Updated Date"
                            SortExpression="lastUpdatedDate"
                            DataField="lastUpdatedDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="User"
                            SortExpression="lastUser"
                            DataField="lastUser" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Database Row Id"
                            Visible="true"
                            SortExpression="dbRowId"
                            DataField="dbRowId" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="rowId"
                            DataField="rowId" />
                        <asp:BoundField
                            HeaderText="Comment"
                            Visible="true"
                            SortExpression="comment"
                            DataField="comment" />

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

protected void inputGrid_Sorting3(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the top bracket of the inputGrid_Sorting3 method I never hit it when I click the header at the top of one of the sortable columna.

Comment: Why not put some code in there and set a break point on it and see if it gets hit?

Comment: If you set the break point on the top bracket of the method it will stop there if the method is entered. I have tried letting Visual Studio auto create the sort method and it still doesn't hit it. That is with or without code in it. Compile is clean, it just seems to ignore the OnSorting property of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what the problem was. When you click the header to sort a column it was first going to a row command method in the code page before it reached the sort method. The row command code was blowing up and stopping the flow through to the sort method. I didn't know that the row command event would be fired when I tried to sort the grid. I took the update panel code out of the .aspx page temporarily and then saw the debug go to the row command method instead of the sort method. I put an "if" condition around the row command method code so it could flow through to the sort method. Now it works.